# Is there something like a "really nice mock"?

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito, easymock

Nice mocks in both EasyMock and Mockito are a good thing to start with if you do not want to define behaviour for everything and if you do not want to restrict calls on that mock.

But for me they have one big flaw: They always return `null` if the return type of the method is `Object` or anything inheriting from `Object`.

I am wondering if there is something in one or both of the frameworks that returns `Optional.empty()` for methods that return `Optional<?>` or `Collections.emptyList()` for methods that return `List<?>` and so on...

I wasn't yet able to find anything like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current versions for Mockito return empty Lists and Optionals by default. AFAIK this was a new feature of version 2.0 (at least Optionals). The following test is successful with Mockito 2.27.0.

```java
class MockitoTest
    static class SomeType {
        Optional<String> headline;
        List<String> texts;

        Optional<String> getHeadline() {
            return headline;
        }

        List<String> getTexts() {
            return texts;
        }
    }

    @Test
    void mock_returns_empty_List_by_default() {
        SomeType o = mock(SomeType.class);

        List<String> texts = o.getTexts();

        assertEquals(emptyList(), texts);
    }

    @Test
    void mock_returns_empty_Optional_by_default() {
        SomeType o = mock(SomeType.class);

        Optional<String> headline = o.getHeadline();

        assertFalse(headline.isPresent());
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, then it is as simple as using a more current version of the framework.

Comment: @Chris At least for Mockito, that is good practice anyway. That framework is pretty vivid, and they add new features quite often.